# Pixel tracking code not working when redirecting to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pixel, tracking

I'm working on firing tracking pixel code when a form is submitted and redirects the user to a PDF document. Right now I'm not seeing my conversion metrics go up and when I land on the PDF file I getting some form of an error in Safari, the network tracking shows red by not error code.

Here i my current code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
     $('form').on('submit', function($) {
        try{ __pixel({"name": "tracker"}); } 
        catch (err) {} 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

*Ps. I've slightly adjusted the tracking code variable names for privacy.*

My assumption is that the pixel isn't firing completely before the user gets redirected to the PDF. If so, how should I go about doing that?

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if it's my approach or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser leaves the page before the tracking hit actually fires. You need to delay the form submission slightly to account for this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
   $('form').on('submit', function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      if (formIsValid) {
        try{ __pixel({"name": "tracker"}); } 
        catch (err) {}
        var form = this;
        setTimeout(function() { form.submit(); }, 50);
      }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There is an issue with this, it causes a submit regardless of validation on the fields. Essentially can submit a blank form.

Comment: @dvoutt Yes it certainly would - but your original code didn't reference validation at all. How you correct for this depends entirely on how you are doing validation - and the solution can get complicated fast. However the basic premise remains - before actually submitting the form, you need to issue your tracking call and then use `setTimeout` to delay the form submission.

Comment: I'm implementing now working the script that runs the validation. It's a pretty basic validation script.

Comment: I updated the answer - how the `formIsValid` check is performed is up to you. If you use a form validation script that fires on the `submit` event, then this is where it get's complicated.

Comment: The script that was written for me is simply a bunch of "if" checks for empty fields. It only gets to the tracking script if they all pass, otherwise the script stops by returning false. For example `if (fname == null || fname == "") { alert("First name must be filled out"); return false; }`